# Cannot delete a row containing a foreign key

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys, delete-row

I'm having a trouble with deleting a row from my SQLite table that contains a foreign key,

```
                public void deleteUpload(int id) 
            {
                database.delete(MySqlHelper.TABLE_UPLOAD, MySqlHelper.COLUMN_ID_ARTICLE
                        + " = " + id, null);
            }
```

I keep getting this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
>       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1598)
>       at fr.sunIt.database.DataSource.deleteUpload(DataSource.java:183)

Comment: assuming `COLUMN_ID_ARTICLE` is the primary key of the table, what tables have a relationship back to `COLUMN_ID_ARTICLE` as a foreign key?  Must be some or you wouldn't get this error.  Perhaps even a self join this article could be the parent of a child?  Run this to see if the system thinks there are some... `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE sql LIKE '%REFERENCES%' and sql like '%TABLE_UPLOAD%'`

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete all the entries to this foreign key on all the ta
bles it is been referenced

Comment: I'm not trying to delete the primary key.